# Abrir actividad desde una notificacion push

Tags: android, push-notification

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de tipo Hello World que reciba notificaciones PUSH.

Todo funciona correcto, y donde las instalo reciben las notificaciones al ejecutar el script python.

El problema que cuando aparece la notificación no se como hacer que abra la app.

La estructura del proyecto es la siguiente:

- MainActivity.java
- NotificationsListenerService.java
- RegistrationService.java
- TokenRefreshListenerService.java

y un script python send.py

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.sergi.pruebapush;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationService.class);
        startService(i);
    }
}
```

**NotificationsListenerService.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class NotificationsListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
}
```

**RegistrationService.java**

```
package com.example.sergi.pruebapush;

import android.app.IntentService; import android.content.Intent; import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub; import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging; import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

import java.io.IOException;


public class RegistrationService extends IntentService {
    public RegistrationService() {
        super("RegistrationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        InstanceID myID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String registrationToken="";
        try {
            registrationToken = myID.getToken(
                getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,
                        null
                            );
            Log.d("Registration Token", registrationToken);
            GcmPubSub subscription = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
            subscription.subscribe(registrationToken, "/topics/my_little_topic", null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } }
```

Por ultimo el script que ejecuto cada vez que quiero que se envíe una notificación:

**send.py**

```
from urllib2 import *
import urllib
import json
import sys
MY_API_KEY="************************************************"
messageTitle = sys.argv[1]
messageBody = sys.argv[2]
data={
    "to" : "/topics/my_little_topic",
    "notification" : {
        "body" : messageBody,
        "title" : messageTitle,
        "icon" : "ic_launcher"
    }
}
dataAsJSON = json.dumps(data)
request = Request(
"https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
dataAsJSON,
{ "Authorization" : "key="+MY_API_KEY,
"Content-type" : "application/json"
}
)
print urlopen(request).read()
```

Donde puedo controlar la notificación para abrir la app?

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de tu metodo [onHandleIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)) de tu clase RegistrationService puedes crear la notificacion:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);        
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (!extras.isEmpty()){  

    creaNotificacion();

    }        
    GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Dentro puedes llamar el metodo para crear la notificacion a la cual le defines un [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), para abrir la Activity, regularmente se abre la Actividad principal (abre la aplicacion) o algun fragmento dentro de la misma :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("mi mensaje")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificacionIntent =  new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                //Puedes definir valores extras para agregar en el Bundle del Intent.
                /*extras.putInt("seccion", 1);
                extras.putString("mensaje", "Este es mi mensaje");
                extras.putBoolean("esWidget", true);
                notIntent.putExtras(extras);*/
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, notificacionIntent, FLAG_NONE);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

@Sergiocv [onHandleIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)) Se usa para recibir los datos de la push notificacion por parte del servidor de Google, la obtencion del token y el registro se deben realizar previamente, por ejemplo cuando inicias tu aplicacion por primera ocasion.

Comment: Gracias por contestar Elena, el GCMBroadcastReceiver me aparece como desconocido, y buscando por la red encuentro que esta deprecado...se te ocurre algun ejemplo para poder hacerlo con las clases sin deprecar? muchas gracias!

Comment: dame un par de horas y agrego eĺ actual método.

Comment: gracias elena! quedo a la espera!

Comment: todo bien Elena?

Comment: alguna idea que aportar??

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el siguiente código, creando un pending intent y setear en la notificación usar el método setLatestEventInfo.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, y esto exactamente donde encajaria en mi codigo?

Comment: y el objeto notification de donde aparece?

Comment: alguna idea mas que aportar?