# Abrir actividad desde notificacion creada por segunda aplicacion

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo dos aplicaciones en android de las cuales una me genera una notificación en la barra de notificaciones al ocurrir un evento X, bien podría ser una consulta a una base de datos, al conectar el dispositivo a la corriente, etc.

Quisiera saber si existe la forma de abrir la segunda aplicación al seleccionar la notificación generada por la primera aplicación.

No tengo ningún tipo de código pero si una idea y es que se podría llevar a cabo con un BroadcastReceiver pero de ser así no encuentro o más bien no se me ocurre la manera de hacerlo.

¿Se puede realizar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cesar, simplemente debes definir un [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) pero en lugar de abrir una Activity en tu aplicación, abriras una en otra aplicación

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent().setClassName("com.otraaplicacion", "com.otraaplicacion.Activity")
```

Revisa esta respuesta:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13695/95

Sería de esta forma:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText("mi mensaje")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Intent notificacionIntent =  new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
 // Abre Activity de otra aplicación.
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent().setClassName("com.otraaplicacion", "com.otraaplicacion.Activity")

                //Puedes definir valores extras para agregar en el Bundle del Intent.
                /*extras.putInt("seccion", 1);
                extras.putString("mensaje", "Este es mi mensaje");
                extras.putBoolean("esWidget", true);
                notIntent.putExtras(extras);*/
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, notificacionIntent, FLAG_NONE);
                mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: gracias Elenasys lo revisaré y te comento que tal me va