# Notificaciones Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

quisiera saber si alguien podría ayudarme con un detalle que tengo con Android. El escenario es el siguiente:

Tengo un `Webview` que cargo en mi actividad principal, y todo bien, si salgo de la aplicación e ingreso de nuevo no recarga la página.

El problema es cuando recibo una notificación con por `Firebase`, si abro la notificación manda a llamar de nuevo al método `onCreate()` de mi actividad y por consecuente recarga mi `WebView`, situación que quiero evitar. La pregunta es:

> ¿Se puede abrir mi aplicación al hacer click en la notificación sin
>   tener que pasar por el método onCreate()?

Espero alguien me pueda guiar. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Se puede abrir mi aplicación al hacer click en la notificación sin
>   tener que pasar por el método onCreate?

Para abrir la aplicación se realiza mediante un [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), aquí varias respuestas de como realizarlo.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/28862/95

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22127/95

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35726/95

Con respecto a que deseas abrir la aplicación y no deseas que esta tenga que pasar por `onCreate()`, **recuerda que para abrir una Activity necesariamente tienes que pasar por `onCreate()` -> `onStart()` -> `onResume()`**, esto esta definido en el ciclo de vida de la Activity:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto no es posible que no pase por `onCreate()` a menos que tu previamente abras la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Estaré comentando. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Jarbox usando la consola de Firebase no se puede personalizar el evento del click en la notificación. Para hacerlo tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Tienes que hacer un método en la clase firebaseService que al obtener el token lo envíe a una base de datos en algún servidor tuyo dedicado para eso.
2. Tienes que crear tu propia consola, es decir hacer una pequeña app web, donde tengas todos los campos que quieres enviar en tu mensaje ej: titulo, contenido, etc.
3. Una vez que tienes tu html, al momento de hacer "submit" con algún botón, tienes que llamar a un archivo *php*, en ese archivo tienes que poner tu *WebKey* que la obtienes de la consola de *FireBase*. ese archivo *php* va a recibir los datos enviados desde el formulario html, se va a conectar a tu base de datos, va a obtener uno a uno los tokens, se va a comunicar con los servidores de FireBase y va a enviar los datos a cada uno de los dispositivos.
4. En tu clase `FireBaseMessagingService`, implementas el método `onMessageReceived` el cual recibe un parámetro de tipo `RemoteMessage`. para saber si todo fue bien basta con `if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null)` si eso es verdadero obtienes los datos de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   String titulo = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
   String contenido= remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
   ```

en caso de que tengas algún otro tipo de dato y no figure en los *getters*, los obtienes así

```
descuento = remoteMessage.getData().get("discount");
```

esto es una explicación resumida, te dejo el link de como hacerlo. Suerte

[FireBase, Android, php](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiKCEa5_Cs8)

Comment: sí, todo eso ya lo hago amigo, una disculpa por no mencionarlo. Yo hice todo eso que comentas, de echo las notificaciones las obtengo desde la db y las mando con una clase que cree en PHP.

Comment: entonces no entendi que necesitas. explicate mejor

Answer (score 0):

@Gonzalo GM, este es mi código para crear la notificación:

```
private void showNotification(Map<String, String> data) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    //i.putExtra("Activity", data.get("Main"));
    i.putExtra("Activity", "Main");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    long[] pattern = new long[] { 2000, 500, 2000 };

    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(data.get("Title"))
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentText(data.get("Message"))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.redgps)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    int defaults = 0;

    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    builder.setDefaults(defaults);

    Random r = new Random();

    int idNotificacionG = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(idNotificacionG, builder.build());
}
```